# Как следует переводить "Reputation"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Вдохновлённый фразой:

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you;

Я попробовал использовать «Доверие», вместо текущего варианта «Репутация».

Оказалось, что «Доверие» совершенно естественно вписывается на место
"reputation". Вот перевод фраз, относящихся к "reputation", из пары разделов в
Справке:

- You earn reputation when people vote on your posts =

  Вы зарабатываете доверие когда люди голосуют за ваши сообщения
- Your reputation score goes up when others vote up your questions,
  answers and edits. =

  Уровень доверия поднимается когда другие голосуют «За» ваши вопросы,
  ответы и корректировки.
- As you earn reputation, you'll unlock new privileges like the
  ability to vote, comment, and even edit other people's posts. =

  Накапливая доверие, вы получите право голосовать, комментировать, и
  даже изменять сообщений других людей.
- At the highest levels, you'll have access to special moderation
  tools. You'll be able to work alongside our community moderators to
  keep the site focused and helpful. =

  На высших уровнях доверия у вас будет доступ к специальным
  инструментам для модерации. Вы сможете работать вместе с
  общественными модераторами, чтобы поддерживать полезность и
  целенаправленность ресурса(сайта).
- Once you earn 50 reputation, you can comment on anybody's post. =

  Как только вы доведете ваш уровень доверия до 50, вы сможете
  комментировать сообщения, оставленные кем-угодно.
- What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it? =

  Что такое доверие? Как я его заработаю (или потеряю)?
- Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says
  "serial upvoting/downvoting reversed"?

  Почему на моей странице заработанного доверия показано изменение,
  обозначенное как «серийное голосование отменено»?
- Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says
  'User was removed'?

  Почему на моей странице заработанного доверия показано изменение,
  обозначенное как «Пользователь удалён»?
- Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you;

  Уровень доверия -- это грубая мера насколько сообщество вам верит;
- Basic use of the site, including asking questions, answering, and
  suggesting edits, does not require any reputation at all. =

  Основное использование ресурса(сайта), включая возможность спросить
  и ответить на вопрос, предложить корректировку --
  совсем не требует никакого доверия.
- But the more reputation you earn, the more privileges you gain. =

  Но чем больше доверия вы заработаете, тем больше прав вы получите.
- The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and
  useful answers. =

  Первичный способ получить доверие состоит в публикации хороших
  вопросов и полезных ответов.
- Votes on these posts cause you to gain (or sometimes
  lose) reputation. =

  Голоса за эти сообщения увеличивают (или иногда уменьшают) уровень
  доверия.
- Please note that votes for posts marked “community
  wiki” do not generate any reputation. =

  На заметку: голоса за сообщения, отмеченные как «общие», не изменяют
  доверие.
- You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any
  combination of the activities below. =

  Вы можете увеличить уровень доверия не более 200 единиц за день за
  счёт любой комбинации действий, приведённых ниже.
- Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily
  reputation limit. =

  Вознаграждение за конкурсы, принятые ответы и премии за связывание
  учётных записей не подчиняются дневному пределу на прирост уровня
  доверия.
- You gain reputation when:

  - question is voted up: +5
  - answer is voted up: +10
  - If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or
    more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting
    +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user
    restrictions. =

  Доверие к вам растёт когда:

  - голос «За» на вопрос: +5
  - голос «За» на ответе: +10
  - Если вы опытный участник сообщества Stack Exchange c 200 или
    большем уровнем доверия по крайней мере на одном сайте, то вы
    получите +100 прибавку к начальному уровню доверия, чтобы снять
    ограничения, предназначенные для недавних участников.
- You lose reputation when:

  - your question is voted down: −2
  - your answer is voted down: −2
  - All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never
    drop below 1. Accepting your own answer does not gain you any
    reputation. If a user reverses a vote, the corresponding reputation
    loss or gain will be reversed as well. Vote reversal as a result of
    voting fraud will also return lost or gained reputation. =

  Доверие к вам падает когда:

  - получен голос «Против» на вашем вопросе: -2
  - получен голос «Против» на вашем ответе: -2
  - Все участники начинают с одной единицей доверия и уровень доверия
    никогда не может упасть ниже 1. Принятие своего собственного
    ответа не добавляет к вам доверия. Если участник отменит свой
    голос, то соотвествующие изменения в вашем уровне доверия также будут
    отменены.  Отмена голосов из-за обнаружения манипуляции голосов
    также отменяет соотвествующие потери или прирост к доверию.
- At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little
  difference between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators. That
  is intentional. We don’t run this site. The community does.

  На высших уровнях доверия ♦ (алмазные) модераторы и доверенные
  участники мало отличаются. Так и задумано. Сообщество, а не мы,
  управляет своим сайтом.

Comment: да, доверие — очень проникновенный вариант.

Comment: Ну почему же мы выбрали «репутацию»? А «алмазные» модераторы вызывают ассоциации с буддизмом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Голосование, ещё на meta.hashcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

"reputation" = «репутация», «баллы репутации»

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- "reputation" = «уважение», «очки уважения».
- "reputation" = «доверие», «уровень доверия».

Answer (score 5):

По-моему, термин "репутация" является общепринятым для форумов и трогать его не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

на страницах справки:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed
```

в заголовках до сих пор фигурирует слово «уважение» в качестве названия раздела в профиле.

раздел же называется «репутация».

тексты заголовков:

> Почему в моей учётной записи в разделе «Уважение» изменилась репутация и появилось сообщение «Результат голосования исправлен»
>
> Почему в моей учётной записи в разделе «Уважение» изменилась репутация и появилось сообщение «Пользователь был удалён»

Comment: мне кажется, под это стоит сделать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сделал: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803/178576