# раздел, носящий название «репутация», упоминается в справке под именем «уважение»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

**скопировано** из [этого ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/749/178576)

---

на страницах справки:

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed
```

в заголовках до сих пор фигурирует слово «уважение» в качестве названия раздела в профиле.

раздел же называется «репутация».

тексты заголовков:

> Почему в моей учётной записи в разделе «Уважение» изменилась репутация и появилось сообщение «Результат голосования исправлен»
>
> Почему в моей учётной записи в разделе «Уважение» изменилась репутация и появилось сообщение «Пользователь был удалён»

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Поправили!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/803/#comment2312_803) от [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky):

Спасибо за замечание. Поправили!